# Redirect to screen after logging in

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'd like to redirect a user to a view after login a user in with GoogleSignin instead of rendering a view

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Platform, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton } from 'react-native-google-signin'

import DashboardScreen from './Components/DashboardScreen'

// Routes
export const MyNavigator = StackNavigator({
  DashboardScreen: {
    name: 'DashboardScreen',
    description: 'Dasboard available once logged in',
    screen: DashboardScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Dashboard'
    }
  },
});

export default class MyApp extends Component {

  //...

  _signIn() {
    GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then((user) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true,
        user: user
      })

      // Redirect to screen here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Signin error', err)
    })
    .done()
  }

  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```

I tried many things, I think it should be something like this:

```
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'DashboardScreen',
    params: { user: user.givenName }
  })

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
```

But the console says that this.props is undefined.

Would you be able to help?
Thank you!

Comment: `MyApp` should be in the `StackNavigator` as initial page.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `this` inside of `_signIn` is not bound to your class anymore but to the `_signIn` function.

To make it work you could modify `_signIn` into an arrow function :

```
 _signIn = () => {
  GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then((user) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true,
        user: user
      })

      const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'DashboardScreen',
        params: { user: user.givenName }
      })

      this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Signin error', err)
    })
    .done()
}
```

Here is more info about how to bind `this`: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

You have several other articles you could look at as it is a common mistake in React.

Answer (score 0):

please add myApp in stack navigator and follow this

```
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return(
      // your code
      <Button onPress={() => navigate({ routeName: 'DashboardScreen' ,params: { user:userData }}) />
  );
}
```

and you'll get the userData in DashboardScreen using this.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.user
```